# Entity Framework Enable migrations CommandNotFound exception

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have installed Entity Framework thorough nuget. I have VS2019 .net console application.

In the Package Manager console, I run `Enable-Migrations`.

I get exception:

> The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:18
>   + Enable-Migrations <<<<
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-Migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Unless you're developing against something predating .Net Core (EF 6 and lower), you don't need to do enable-migrations. Just run `add-migration InitialCreate -c MyDbContext`

Comment: Entity Framework (.Net, EF 6 and lower) has different NuGet commands than Entity Framework Core.  I suspect you probably either a) installed the wrong version of EF, or b) you have the right version, but the wrong NuGet commands.  QUESTION: Is your .project .Net, or .Net Core?

Comment: My project is .Net. I installed: <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.0" targetFramework="net472" />  I run add-migration InitialCreate -c DealerContext . I still get The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of th
e name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct  try again.
+ add-migration <<<<  InitialCreate -c DealerContext
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (add-migration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Visual Studio 2019 and this worked for me.

1. You need to install first Entity Framework

   ```
   Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease
   ```
2. Then try to make sure that one of your classes inherits data context
3. Try running enable-migrations again.